# Error after certain amount of ajax calls in a loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I have a project where I import an excel file(xlsx). It converts it into an array of objects (each object is a row in the xlsx). I them use a `forEach` loop on the array and create a data object filled by the excel row. Like so:

```
resultArray.forEach((arr) => {
        let data = {
          action: 'addPestChem',
          crop: arr['Crop'] ? arr['Crop'] : null,
          company_name: arr['Company Name'] ? arr['Company Name'] : null,
          product: arr['Product Name'] ? arr['Product Name'] : null,
          substance: arr['Substance'] ? arr['Substance'] : null,
          function: arr['Function'] ? arr['Function'] : null,
          pcs_no: arr['PCS No'] ? arr['PCS No'] : null,
          phi: arr['PHI'] ? arr['PHI'] : null,
          use_by_date: arr['UseByDate'] ? arr['UseByDate'] : null,
          date_of_reg_review: arr['DateofRegReview'] ? arr['DateofRegReview'] : null,
          off_label_approval: arr['OffLabelApproval'] ? arr['OffLabelApproval'] : null,
          latest_time_of_application: arr['LatestTimeOfApplication'] ? arr['LatestTimeOfApplication'] : null,
          max_individual_dose: arr['MaxIndividualDose'] ? arr['MaxIndividualDose'] : null,
          max_total_dose: arr['MaxTotalDose'] ? arr['MaxTotalDose'] : null,
          max_no_applications: arr['MaxNoApplications'] ? arr['MaxNoApplications'] : null,
          method_of_application: arr['Methodof Applic'] ? arr['Methodof Applic'] : null,
          content: arr['Content'] ? arr['Content'] : null,
          comment: arr['Comments'] ? ['Comments'] : null
        };

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/assets/ajax/excel_ajax_handler.php",
            type: "POST",
            data
        })
        .done((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .fail(function($xhr) {
            var data = $xhr.responseJSON;
            alert('An Error occured: ');
            console.log(data.message);
        });

      });
```

So after I declare the `data` object I make an ajax call to my handler. Right now for test purposes I have the handler `echo 1`, in the console it returns 1 around 118 times then the `.fail()` starts getting triggered. No idea why this is, anyone have any idea?

Comment: You are using AJAX inside a loop. So it triggers the number of times loop execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ajax in a loop.

Instead do this

```
document.getElementById('uploadAll').addEventListener('click',post)
```

```js
let cnt = 0
const post = () => {
  if (cnt >= resultArray.length) return;
  const arr = resultArray[cnt]
  const data = {
    action: 'addPestChem',
    crop:                       arr['Crop']                    || null,
    company_name:               arr['Company Name']            || null,
    product:                    arr['Product Name']            || null,
    substance:                  arr['Substance']               || null,
    function:                   arr['Function']                || null,
    pcs_no:                     arr['PCS No']                  || null,
    phi:                        arr['PHI']                     || null,
    use_by_date:                arr['UseByDate']               || null,
    date_of_reg_review:         arr['DateofRegReview']         || null,
    off_label_approval:         arr['OffLabelApproval']        || null,
    latest_time_of_application: arr['LatestTimeOfApplication'] || null,
    max_individual_dose:        arr['MaxIndividualDose']       || null,
    max_total_dose:             arr['MaxTotalDose']            || null,
    max_no_applications:        arr['MaxNoApplications']       || null,
    method_of_application:      arr['Methodof Applic']         || null,
    content:                    arr['Content']                 || null,
    comment:                    arr['Comments']                || null
  };

  console.log(data);

  $.ajax({
      url: "/assets/ajax/excel_ajax_handler.php",
      type: "POST",
      data
    })
    .done((res) => {
      process(res); // make a function that handles the result
      cnt++
      setTimeout(post,1000);
    })
    .fail(function($xhr) {
      var data = $xhr.responseJSON;
      alert('An Error occured: ');
      console.log(data.message);
    });

};
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing anything, I have a button click listener to trigger this, put this code in the event handler, and replaced `process(res)` with `console.log(res)`

Comment: No logs in the console or network tab. I have made an edit with my updated code based on your answer

Comment: `document.getElementById('uploadAll').addEventListener('click', post)`

Comment: Working! Thank you! There is over 6k rows in the file so it will take a while haha Does the set timeout have to be 1000ms or can I bump it down

Comment: You can remove it or set to 100ms  but I suggest you keep it to not hammer the server.

Comment: Why do you not get a bigger chunk then?

Comment: I'll experiment with it and see can I get to even 500ms and see if it still works, bigger chunk?

Comment: Yes, If you need to have this loop over 6000 lines, perhaps you send the whole file and get a complete set back?

Comment: I'll work with what I have for now and if I need to I'll look into that :)